# golang tcp listen window

Tags: windows, go, network-programming

I am bringing up TCP listener in windows OS, not sure how to receive data from listener and send to command line

In Unix we do as follows:

```
service := ":1200"
tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", service)

listener, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp",tcpAddr)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}

defer listener.Close()
file, err := listener.File()//--> unix supports file descriptor / how about in windows ??
if err != nil {  
    return "", err
}

cmd := exec.Command(execname)
cmd.ExtraFiles = []*os.File{file}//--> in unix it support / how about in windows to add data ???
cmd.Start()
```

How to bring up in windows to listen on tcp ipaddress and send to executable file?

Comment: https://golang.org/src/net/tcpsock.go?s=227:332#L5  (NOT IMPLEMENTED IN WINDOWS any suggestion )